# How to get a value from vec3 in vertex shader? OpenGL 3.3

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I have the following vertex shader:

```
#version 330                                                                      
layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;                                           
uniform mat4 gWVP;                                                                
out vec4 Color;
void main()                                                                       
{                                                                                 
    gl_Position = gWVP * vec4(Position, 1.0);                     
};
```

How can I get, for example, the third value of vec3? The first my thought was: "Maybe I can get it by multiplying this vector(Position) on something?" But I am not sure that something like "vertical vector type" exists.
So, what is the best way? I need this value to set the color of the pixel.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: OpenGL Shading Language.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: The language is called GLSL; the `glsl` tag and mentioning *OpenGL Shaders* should have given plenty of hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each vector has overloaded access to elements.  In this case, using `Position.z`  should work.

Answer (score 17):

There are at least 4 options:

1. You can access vector components with component names `x`, `y`, `z`, `w`. This is mostly used for vectors that represent points/vectors. In your example, that would be `Position.z`.
2. You can use component names `r`, `g`, `b`, `a`. This is mostly used for vectors that represent colors. In your example, you could use `Position.b`, even though that would not be very readable. On the other hand, `Color.b` would be a good option for the other variable.
3. You can use component names `s`, `t`, `p`, `q`. This is mostly used for vectors that represent texture coordinates. In our example, `Position.p` would also give you the 3rd component.
4. You can use the subscript notation with 0-based indices. In your example, `Position[2]` also gives he 3rd element.